# R Temporary File being created

Tags: php, r, random-forest

So here's what's happening. We currently run an R program in the cloud and import a package (`randomForest`) specifically.

When we invoke the command (through `PHP`), I can see this temporary file (`.RDataTmp`) being created.

I believe what it's doing is loading the package during this time. Problem is it takes about 25 seconds for it to load this package (40MB) and I'm looking to see if there's a way I can come up with a solution from it loading it every-time.

I've tried commenting this line out:

```
--load("xxxx.RData")--
```

in my code but it still creates that temporary file (`.RDataTmp`).

Is there a way to keep the temporary file in memory as `RData` doesn't change at all? Or any other to speed up performance?

This is being run on `Amazon EC2 m1.large fwiw`.